# Accessing style elements

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, templatebinding

I have a slider style (cut version)

```
<Style x:Key="SliderThumb" TargetType="Thumb">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                <Ellipse Height="15" Width="15" Fill="White"></Ellipse>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="Slider" TargetType="Slider">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Track Grid.Row="1" x:Name="PART_Track"   >
            <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource SliderRepeatButton1}"  Command="Slider.DecreaseLarge" />
            </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
            <Track.Thumb>
                <Thumb Style="{StaticResource SliderThumb}"  />
            </Track.Thumb>
            <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource SliderRepeatButton}" Command="Slider.IncreaseLarge" />
            </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
        </Track>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style x:Key="BigSliderStyle" TargetType="Slider">
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="21" />
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="104" />
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource Slider}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

From my interface I create it as

```
<Slider Style="{StaticResource BigSliderStyle}"/>
```

I need to bind a tooltip to slider thumb only which relates to ellipse.
Is there any way to access ellipse properties from within form XAML?

Comment: Can you just put `ToolTip="{TemplateBinding Tag}` on the `Ellipse` and piggy back your `ToolTip` content in via the `Tag` tag? Then just do `<Slider Tag="The Tooltip Stuff or Binding}"/>` I didn't test it but it's what I'd probably try first.

Comment: Your slider should be bound to something. That something should have the tooltip value as a property. Then you can just bind, in the style, the tooltip to its source property. You probably could also overload the `Tag` property for that purpose, but it being a dependency property on the parent object, it would need to be bound to something anyway, so you might as well just bind straight to the model object.

Comment: Actually I tried this 
....
    <Ellipse ToolTip="{TemplateBinding Tag}"/>
.....
    <Slider Tag="test" Style="{StaticResource BigSliderStyle}"/>

And it does not work

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```
<Style x:Key="SliderThumb" TargetType="Thumb">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="ToolTip"><!--just add this part to your code-->
        <Setter.Value>
            <TextBlock Text="Some text"/><!-- also you can use Text="{Binding propertyName}"-->
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter><!--just add this part to your code-->
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                <Ellipse Height="15" Width="15" Fill="White"></Ellipse>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You already have the access to the thumb through the style. That element supports the Tooltip out of the box so no need to focus on the `ellipse`, as that is only a `template` for `thumb` placeholder.
This will also allow you to use different templates for the `Slider` keeping you `ToolTip` throughout the app.

Comment: The value of the ToolTip is not static (it displays current position of the video) and I need to bind it to some property of the class. I cannot do that with style apparently but from withing class XAML

Comment: @sergman You can replace "Some text" with Binding, if your position is stored in a view model.

Comment: Yes, this worked, though I though I can have more universal approach so the style is not aware of specific binding. This way I can use the same style in different classes which one will bind to its own property. But I can live with that.

Comment: If your app has a unified way of displaying progress i.e. every control has a specific View Model then you don't have to worry about this. If however every view model slightly differs from others than no matter what you do it would be impossible to locate the correct property.